# Making precise that smallest sigma algebra that makes random variables measurable quantifies knowledge

Tags: probability, measure-theory, random-variables

Suppose that $X_1, X_2: (\Omega, \mathcal{A}) \to (\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ are independent random variables with distribution Unif$\lbrack 0, 1 \rbrack $.

Consider the map $Y=X_1+X_2$.
Then $\sigma(Y)$ is the smallest sigma algebra that makes $Y$ measurable.
Intuitively,  $\sigma(Y)$ quantifies knowledge of the sum $X_1+X_2$, but not the individual elements.

Is there a nice way to make that precise?

Comment: If $f$ is not injective, then one has $\sigma (f(X)) \subsetneq \sigma(X)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if $X,Y$ are random variables on the same probability space then it
can be proved that  $\sigma(X)\subseteq\sigma(Y)$ iff $X=f(Y)$ for some a Borel-measurable function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

So if sum $Y=X_1+X_2$ would quantify the knowledge of e.g. $X_1$ in the sense that $\sigma(X_1)\subseteq\sigma(Y)$ then $X_1=f(Y)$ for some Borel-measurable function $f$.

This however would mean that $Y$ determines $X_1$ which is not true.

Comment: So this means that $\sigma(Y) \subset \sigma(X_1) \cup \sigma(X_2)$?

Comment: @FrederikRavnKlausen No, but it means that $\sigma(Y)\subseteq \sigma(X_1,X_2)$ where $\sigma(X_1,X_2)$ denotes the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ such that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are both measurable. We do have $\sigma(X_1)\cup\sigma(X_2)\subseteq\sigma(X_1,X_2)$ but in most cases that inclusion is strict. A union of two $\sigma$-algebras is not necessarily a $\sigma$-algebra.